# How can I get this query to output for multiple values in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which will give me the average size in bytes for a given table name.

I intend to use it as an estimate for a sql result set, for example, a 100 byte table has 100 rows, it'll work out each row may be 1 byte. Therefore a select on the table with a where clause that returns 25 rows may be estimated to be 25 bytes.

It's a rudimentary capacity planner. Which having looked at other possible methods, i'd prefer compared to anything that is reliant on stats.

I have tried the code below, which works fine for 1 table.

```
SELECT a.total_bytes / b.num_rows avg_row_size
FROM (SELECT SUM(bytes) total_bytes
FROM dba_extents
WHERE owner = 'KEVIN'
AND segment_name = 'KEVS_TABLE' ) a,
(SELECT COUNT(*) num_rows
FROM KEVS_TABLE) b
```

However, i'd like this to loop through and give results for a whole load of tables. I've tried:

```
SELECT a.total_bytes / b.num_rows avg_row_size
FROM (SELECT SUM(bytes) total_bytes
FROM dba_extents
WHERE 
segment_name in (select table_name from table_list) ) a,
(SELECT COUNT(*) num_rows
FROM table_list) b
```

But it just returns nothing.

Any ideas how I can get it to return a value for each row in the table_list?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are overcomplicating this. As far as concerned, Oracle system view [`ALL_TABLES`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2105.htm#REFRN20286) gives you the information you are looking for, in column `AVG_ROW_LEN`.

The documentation says:

> `AVG_ROW_LEN` - `NUMBER` : Average length of a row in the table (in bytes)

NB: `AVG_ROW_LENGTH` is populated only if statistics have been collected on the corresponding table.

So you should be able to use a query like:

```
SELECT table_name, avg_row_length FROM all_tables WHERE owner = 'KEVIN';
```

Or, if you want to check all tables in your current schema, just use [`USER_TABLES`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_5443.htm#REFRN26286):

```
SELECT table_name, avg_row_length FROM user_tables;
```

NB: please note that `ALL_TABLES` (and `USER_TABLES`) contains many other information that can be useful for your use case, provided the related tables are analyzed recently, i.e. magnitude of data close to real-time, for example:

- `NUM_ROWS`: Number of rows in the table
- `BLOCKS`: Number of used data blocks in the table (you can multiply that with the block size of the tablespace that hosts the table to compute its total size in bytes)
- `LAST_ANALYZED`: Date on which this table was most recently analyzed

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - much appreciated! But, I did say in my original question that I did not want something that was reliant on stats. I believe this result will only be reliable if you have gathered stats recently... which is as you say also. Unfortunately I'm not confident on how often they are gathered and have no control over it.

Comment: Still stuck with this... anyone else have any ideas :-(

Comment: @Dave: I think that the above solution really is the correct way to go... Are you sure that stats are not up to date in your database? You can have a look at column LAST_ANALYZED in ALL_TABLES to verify that.

Comment: The table has a huge amount of updates and deletes skewing the count a lot throughout the day. I need the figures from at the moment I execute the query to be as accurate as possible. The gather stats job only runs over night.